What if oscillation-based computing is the generalization of quantum computing?
This question contains both engineering perspectives and science perspectives.
Here is my definition about oscillation-based computing:

Oscillation-based computing is the computation where the input and the output are oscillating. Therefore, the input and output have properties of general waves such as amplitude, phase, frequency (spatial dimension), and time (temporal dimension).

If we consider frequency as space, and period as time. Then, there must be space-time tradeoff between them about computation resources.
It's supported by the argument that the frequency and the time are inversely proportional:
$ f = 1/T$
For example, the quantum computer minimizes the temporal dimension, leaving no gap for the time, but trades off the number of logic gates used, which relies on spatial dimension. Conversely, the Turing Machine minimizes the spatial dimension as minimize as possible but trades off the computation time, which relies on temporal dimension.
GPU-based computing is also using space-time tradeoff but relies on the number of logic gates used (e.g., the number of ALUs used).
However, oscillation-based computing gives flexibility about how much space (specifically the frequency) so that the computation time is also affected. Theoretically, if we increase the frequency near infinity (smaller wave length, which leads to the quantum world), it would have the same performance as quantum computing.
In classical computing, the binary counter explores from zero to the maximum value of the bits, where the most significant bit requires more time to change its state. The number of prescaler is the number of bits.

However, in oscillation-based computing, the prescaler itself is used for interference, and the number of prescaler is used for the phase rotation resolution. E.g. 3 prescalers (including global clock pulse which has highest frequency) would have rotate-step $ \pi / (3+1) $ or $45^\circ$.
For example, the image below has 3 prescalers so we can phase shift like how T-gate works.

Using the phase shift, we can perform interference like constructive interference or destructive interference. In fact, it's not the phase shift that causing interference. Looks the image above, to perform phase shift, we have to perform basic interference which is using AND gate (destructive interference that nullify state 1) and OR gate (constructive interference that boost state 1) based on reference of high frequency (frequency ground) and low frequency. For example, the image below causing probability of 25% for state 1, and probability of 75% for state 0 by the AND gate interference when sampled. Conversely for the OR gate interference.

We can conclude, the pulse-width (duty cycle) of the wave is acting as amplitude probability that something can be tuned based on interference of classical logic gate when sampled by clock that has higher frequency than them (consider Nyquist theorem). E.g. pulse-width of 50% gives equal superposition of state 0 and state 1 (analog with Hadamard gate).
Performing simple NOT gate when the input is oscillated (superposition) is basically rotating the phase of signal by 180 degree.
For the summary, oscillation-based computing has same properties like quantum-computing.

Superposition
Entanglement
Interference Capability

For, entanglement, I have this simple snippet python code for bell state to simulate oscillation-based computing:
from time import time_ns
from collections import Counter

# param
T = 1_000_000 # global clock in ns

# oscillator init
osc0 = 0
osc1 = 0
h = 0 # hadamard gate

# period init
now = time_ns()
t0 = now
t1 = now
t2 = now
t_start = now

# sampler init
sampler = []

while now - t_start < 5_000_000_000: # stop program after 5 seconds sampling
  
    # prescalers
    if now - t0 > T:
      t0 = now
      osc0 ^= 1 # pulsing
      if now - t1 > T * 2:
          t1 = now
          osc1 ^= 1 # pulsing
          if now - t2 > T * 4:
              t2 = now
              h ^= 1 # pulsing hadamard gate
    
    # bell state
    q0 = h
    q1 = 0
    q1 ^= q0 # perform XOR operation (CNOT)
    
    c = (q1 << 1) | (q0) # measurement
    sampler.append(c) # sampling
    now = time_ns() # update time
    
# print result
for key, val in Counter(sampler).items():
    print(bin(key)[2:].zfill(2), val)

Output:
00 3178506
11 3155527

=== Code Execution Successful ===

For the question, is there something I missed with this setup so I can say safely that the oscillation-based computing is the generalization of quantum computing? Since oscillation-based computing has the same properties like quantum computing (superposition, entanglement, interference). Because theoritically, if we set the period of global clock near zero, it will performing near performance as quantum computing.

Oscillation based computing differ from quantum computing. Difference comes from quantum mechanics in quantum computing and classical wave mechanism in oscillation based computing.

Superposition

Superposition: Qubits can exist in multiple states simultaneously (e.g., |0⟩ and |1⟩) governed by a wave function.
State Collapse: Upon measurement, the superposition collapses to one definite state.
Classical Overlap: Signals can combine using different frequencies or phases.
No Collapse: Overlapping waves remain separate and don’t represent multiple outcomes simultaneously.

Entanglement

Quantum Entanglement: Qubits can be entangled, creating non-local correlations where the state of one instantly affects another, regardless of distance.
Classical Synchronization: Oscillators can synchronize or correlate locally, but each retains its individual properties without the deep, non-local connections of entangled qubits.

Interference Capability

Quantum Interference: Utilizes probabilistic wave functions to enhance or cancel computational paths.
Classical Interference: Involves deterministic constructive or destructive interference of waves, limited to linear superposition without the complex, probabilistic manipulations found in quantum algorithms.

This is exactly same as GPT answer that I was asked about. 1) Oscillating signal is analog to superposition, specifically for pulse width 50% gives equal superposition. 2) The state of one instantly affect another, it's the same like my python code above. Where q1 depends on q0. 3) Complex number, is about phase, it does support phase shifting.

What is your problem with that answer? Only with quantum mechanics and wave particle duality answer from computation is not classical. Without quantum part it is fundamentally different form of computation.

I mean, those of three, are also applied in oscillation-based computing. So, it seems the only difference is about frequency or how fast the hardware sampling.

For example, the equal superposition in oscillation-based computing can be applied with square-wave where the pulse-width is 50%. The only difference with quantum computing, it doesn't explicitly state how much the frequency of oscillation particle should be used, as the frequency in quantum computing idealy near infinity (smallest wavelength)

Those three are there in oscillation based computing, but they are different. They give you results from classical wave mechanics. Quantum computers give you answers based on quantum mechanics.

I see, so I can safely say quantum computing can be emulated with classical waves.
